# Romanian IMO TST 2006, day 4, problem 3

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n>1$ be an integer. A set $S \subset \{ 0,1,2, \ldots, 4n-1\}$ is called rare if, for any $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, the following two conditions take place at the same time

(1) the set $S\cap \{4k-2,4k-1,4k, 4k+1, 4k+2 \}$ has at most two elements;

(2) the set $S\cap \{4k+1,4k+2,4k+3\}$ has at most one element.

Prove that the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,4n-1\}$ has exactly $8 \cdot 7^{n-1}$ rare subsets.I got this solution from AOPS:

I believe that the formula $7^n$ is incorrect.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of rare subsets of $\{0,1,\dots,4n-1\}$ and $g(n)$ be the number of rare subsets such that they do not contain $4n-1$ or $4n-2$.
Considering all cases of (not) containing elements $4n-4$, $4n-3$, $4n-2$, $4n-1$ we get
[ \begin{array}{l}f(n) = 6 f(n-1) + 2 g(n-1)\\g(n) = 3 f(n-1) + g(n-1)\end{array} ]
Since the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 6 & 2\\ 3 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ is $x^2-7x$, for $n>1$ we have $f(n) = 7 f(n-1)$ that together with $f(1)=8$ implies $f(n)=8\cdot 7^{n-1}$.

My problem is in finding recurrent functions totally we have $6$ cases for (not) containing elements $4n-4$, $4n-3$, $4n-2$, $4n-1$ and in every cases we can have at most $f(n-1)$ solution so how is possible $f(n) = 6 f(n-1) + 2 g(n-1)$?Please explain me how we got two recurrent relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $S$ is a rare subset of $\{0, \dots, 4n-1\}$, then the $8$ possible cases for $S \cap \{4n-4,4n-3,4n-2,4n-1\}$ are 
$\varnothing, \{4n-1\}, \{4n-1,4n-4\}, \{4n-2\}, \{4n-2,4n-4\}, \{4n-3\}, \{4n-3,4n-4\}$ and $\{4n-4\}$.

Can you see how we derive the recursion $f(n) = 6f(n-1) + 2g(n-1)$ from this?

Then let $S$ be a rare subset of $\{0, \dots, 4n-1\}$ containing 
neither $4n-1$ nor $4n-2$. What are the possibilities for $S \cap \{4n-4,4n-3,4n-2,4n-1\}$ now? Use this to derive the recursion $g(n) = 3f(n-1) + g(n-1)$.